# Apache not seeing subdirectories of /var/www

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to get a basic site running under Apache 2. Eventually I'm aming to use mod_wsgi to serve a django applictation, but for now I've started with a really simple variation of the default virtual host, currently just showing a directory listing of /var/www. The problem I'm having is that the server can't seem to see the directory "/var/www/mysite". Viewing www.mysite.com/ gives me a listing as expected of /var/www directory, but only shows the files, not directories.

Please can anybody tell me if there's something obvious that I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance

Virtual Hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Listing of /var/www (including security context 'ls -Zl /var/www')

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data ?   45 Jul 14 15:37 index.html__
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data ?   91 Aug  9 14:19 index2__.html
drw-r--r-- 2 www-data www-data ? 4096 Aug  9 14:36 mysite
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the permissions of the mysite directory so that the apache user has execute permission on it:

```
chmod a+x mysite
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Knew it must be something simple :) All working now. Just mod_wsgi to go now!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the read access permission on the sub folder

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/subfolder 
Or 
chmod -R 775 /var/www/subfolder
```

as per your sub directory structure